# Select distinct values from union

Tags: sql, distinct, union

I have three tables (sales orders, invoices, purchase orders)

```
sales_order
------------
so_id (primary key)
item_id (foreign key)
entry_date

invoice
------------
invc_id (primary key)
item_id (foreign key)
entry_date

purchase_order
------------
po_id (primary key)
item_id (foreign key)
entry_date
```

and they all refer to one central table (item):

```
item_id (pk)
```

I am trying to write a sql query that will return all items with activity within a date range.

This is what I've come up with:

```
select distinct item_id from sales_order where entry_date between ? and ?
union
select distinct item_id from invoice where entry_date between ? and ?
union
select distinct item_id from purchase where entry_date between ? and ?
```

I think this is the correct solution, but I'm not sure how to test it.

Question 1:
Does the "distinct" keyword apply to all of the statements or only to each statement? i.e., will each query return a distinct set but when you "union" them together it can show duplicates?

Question 2:
Is there a way to return the total (unique) item count (as a separate query)? Like:

```
select count(
    select distinct item_id from sales_order where entry_date between ? and ?
    union
    select distinct item_id from invoice where entry_date between ? and ?
    union
    select distinct item_id from purchase where entry_date between ? and ?
)
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct` is redundant.  I usually write such as query as:

```
select item_id from sales_order where entry_date between ? and ?
union  -- intentionally removing duplicates
select item_id from invoice where entry_date between ? and ?
union
select item_id from purchase where entry_date between ? and ?;
```

To return the total count, you can use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select item_id from sales_order where entry_date between ? and ?
      union  -- intentionally removing duplicates
      select item_id from invoice where entry_date between ? and ?
      union
      select item_id from purchase where entry_date between ? and ?
     ) i;
```

Comment: Does `union` remove duplicates on all RDBMS'? Specifically, I'm using Oracle

Comment: @ryvantage . . . Yes, that is how `union` is defined in the ANSI standard.  I generally recommend that you use `union all` by default.  It does not incur the overhead of removing duplicates (but you want to do that in this case!).

Comment: Would it be better to remove duplicates on the software layer rather than the database? i.e., iterate through the result set, store the values in a hash, and throw out duplicates?

Comment: @ryvantage  . . . Definitely not.  You should do database operations in the database.